# Change width for Bootstrap layout gutter

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to change it but it's not working, here is my relative code:
Style:

```
.row.no-gutters {
            margin-right: 0;
            margin-left: 0;
        }
        .row.no-gutters > [class^="col-"],
        .row.no-gutters > [class*=" col-"] {
            padding-right: 0;
            padding-left: 0;
        }
```

html:

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <span>
                                        Case Number
                                    </span>
                                </div>                                    
                                <div class="col-sm-2" vcenter>
                                    <input class="easyui-textbox" readonly ng-model="caseid"
                                        style="width:60px;height:32px;background-color:#72A4D2">
                                </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Added Fiddle
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f6wtznwd/2/)

Another screenshot:
[image]

Comment: what about using `important!`?

Comment: just checkthis: https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/ and please, more code or an example on jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net this would make everything easier for us to see.

Comment: Added Fiddle example

Comment: I don't know what are you triying to do, how do you expect to see it? did you check [the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)?

Comment: What I want is regardless of what type of a column I am using its width is always equal its actual content. So, even I say lg-12 it should only take as much as a text width is. So, next column should start from the end of text + gutter width.

Comment: See another screenshot. My problem is how to make a gap between boxes smaller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102047/discussion-between-mikevelazco-and-mark).